# Install Matlab 2017 (UBUNTU 18.04)

Tags: mount, iso, matlab

I'm trying to install matlab for 2 days now . I've tried everything but all these mount commands are not working .
So finally I just got to the directory and pressed ./install on the install file .
I though I finally fixed it , but at 72% it asks me to insert the dvd2 , that is an iso file .
How can I do it ? I don't know any commands and I saw lot of thing on forums . 
Everyone says to mount and unmount , but as I said it's not working on me .

[matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1yE4.png)

[matlab2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiNjN.png)

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM5sH.png)

Answer (score 0):

So , I didn't know it , but when I unmounted the iso2 file , i just pressed ok and it started without commads . I guess that's it...

Now I just need help to make an icon to start up the program without going to terminal everytime